# Why does my PreparedStatement.executeUpdate return 0, when rows are confirmed updated?

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, prepared-statement

I have a TSQL-preparedStatement for updating a single register in a table, based on ID. This register also might have connections to a many-to-many relation, which should be updated. In other words new relations should be added, and some relations might need to be deleted.

Here is pseudocode (full SQL code in the end):

- Begin Transaction
- update Booking, set values, Where bookingID = X
- Delete from BookingHasSeat Where bookingID = X and SeatID NOT IN [list of integers]
  the next lines repeat for each int id (Y) in the list
- IF X, Y doesn't already exist, insert X, Y into BookingHasSeat.
- Commit Transaction

The SQL works perfectly, but when I build the statement as a `java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement`, and call the .executeUpdate()-method, I want to store the returned integer value, to make sure at least one row has been updated. If no rows has been updated, it should mean that an update has been unsuccessful, and I report failure to the user application interface.

This TSQL in particular returns failure if the list of seats remain the same as it was. Even if the booking register details were updated. I would expect it to return 1 if the booking was updated, and only return 0 when nothing has happened at all.

How does the returned row count work in TSQL? Is the java-method not compatible with TSQL? How can I make sure that an update has occurred?

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON 
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
DECLARE @BookingID INT = 33; 
UPDATE Booking SET DateTime=6543546, PersonID=4, Comment='', Confirmed='true', StartDate=43265436534, EndDate=-1, StartSession=720, EndSession=900  WHERE BookingID = @BookingID;
DELETE FROM BookingHasSeat WHERE BookingID = @BookingID AND SeatID NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6); 
DECLARE @SeatID1 INT = 1; 
IF @SeatID1 NOT IN (SELECT SeatID FROM BookingHasWorkStation WHERE BookingID = @BookingID) 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO BookingHasSeat (BookingID, SeatID) VALUES (@BookingID, @SeatID1); 
END 
DECLARE @SeatID2 INT = 2; 
IF @SeatID2 NOT IN (SELECT SeatID FROM BookingHasWorkStation WHERE BookingID = @BookingID) 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO BookingHasWorkStation (BookingID, SeatID) VALUES (@BookingID, @SeatID2); 
END 
DECLARE @SeatID3 INT = 3; 
IF @SeatID3 NOT IN (SELECT SeatID FROM BookingHasWorkStation WHERE BookingID = @BookingID) 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO BookingHasWorkStation (BookingID, SeatID) VALUES (@BookingID, @SeatID3); 
END 
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: In my experience relying on the number or rows updated as returned from methods like `executeUpdate` is unnecessary. You want things to run as fast as possible and if I ever run a script like that, I start with `SET NOCOUNT ON;`. The return in that case (for all statements in the script) is -1. Each count has to be sent seperately and in some instances this bogs down execution speed.

Answer (score -1):

When calling a stored procedure with JDBC, you should use CallableStatement.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment.